# How can I enable pytorch GPU support in Google Colab?

Tags: gpu, pytorch, google-colaboratory

How can I enable pytorch to work on GPU?

I've installed pytorch successfully in google colab notebook:
[image]
Tensorflow reports GPU to be in place:

[image]

But torch.device function fails somehow:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8u8T.png It works when I try it.

Answer (score 7):

I hit the same issue.

Try installing Torch like this:

```
# http://pytorch.org/
from os import path
from wheel.pep425tags import get_abbr_impl, get_impl_ver, get_abi_tag
platform = '{}{}-{}'.format(get_abbr_impl(), get_impl_ver(), get_abi_tag())

accelerator = 'cu80' #'cu80' if path.exists('/opt/bin/nvidia-smi') else 'cpu'
print('Platform:', platform, 'Accelerator:', accelerator)

!pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall -q http://download.pytorch.org/whl/{accelerator}/torch-0.4.0-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl torchvision

import torch
print('Torch', torch.__version__, 'CUDA', torch.version.cuda)
print('Device:', torch.device('cuda:0'))
```

The output should be:

> Platform: cp36-cp36m Accelerator: cu80 Torch 0.4.0 CUDA 8.0.61
>   Device: cuda:0

Some snippets floating around use `torch-0.3.0.post4-{platform}-linux_x86_64.whl`, which will lead to the same error, because `device` is a Torch 4 feature.  If you have already installed the wrong version, you may need to do `!pip uninstall torch`.

Also be sure to enable GPU under *Edit > Notebook settings > Hardware accelerator*.

Answer (score 6):

You can enable GPU by clicking on "Change Runtime Type" under the "Runtime" menu. There is also "TPU" support available in these days.

[image: Runtime Menu]

[image: Runtime options]

You can define define `device` using `torch.device`:

```
import torch

DEVICE = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this tutorial: https://medium.com/@nrezaeis/pytorch-in-google-colab-640e5d166f13

For example for CUDA 9.2 and Python 3.6:

```
!pip3 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu92/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
!pip3 install torchvision
```

Now to check the GPU device using PyTorch:

```
torch.cuda.get_device_name(0)
```

My result in Google Colab is Tesla K80.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to having GPU enabled under the menu "Runtime" -> Change Runtime Type, GPU support is enabled with:

```
import torch

if torch.cuda.is_available():
  device = torch.device("cuda")
else:
  device = torch.device("cpu")
```